# MySQL - DISTINCT with HAVING SUM

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, distinct, having

I have a table with the following columns:

- `customerID` - customer IDs with multiple rows with same ID
- `actionVal` - 0 or 1

I want to count how many customers (`customerID`) have more then one row with (`actionVal`) equal to 1

I came up with this SQL statement with no luck...

```
SELECT customerID, SUM(actionVal), COUNT(DISTINCT customerID) as total_C
FROM table1 
GROUP BY customerID 
HAVING SUM(actionVal) > 1
```

The result I'm looking for would be ['total_C']

Comment: And why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, you just need to count the customers from your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_C
FROM (
  SELECT customerID, SUM(actionVal)
  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY customerID 
  HAVING SUM(actionVal) > 1
) as q;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to count the rows returned by your query .
Something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
SELECT customerID, SUM(actionVal) as act_sum
FROM table1 
GROUP BY customerID 
HAVING act_sum > 1
) AS tab
```

I hope this helped.